# Large file truncated on Azure Verizon CDN - is there a timeout of request setting?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I uploaded a 295437KB file to Azure private Blob. I connected Azure Verizon Premium CDN via an app service that streams it from the Blob. The file returned is truncated, at different lengths, less than the full file length. Several 10s of MB shorter.
I have checked the file size on the Blob (correct) and also tested the call that retrieves it from the App Service (correct).
So it appears to be on the CDN side. Is there some timeout or request limit I can set on the CDN to alleviate this?

Here is an example of a CDN call that truncates the file:

https://holojem-prod-files-cdn.azureedge.net/artifacts/11/283/332/0008%20Watch%20This%20Video.mp4?DYiNiOt7Q_9xGaZhscklXmcn0tlpDU649hQUD2n7WzgxfirhVQyzwch2-szLjDmUjAshEfe2ZsQ6ejEDR46QvHVKf5WneWFAz1vOQppOPfcBq3KCS11mZ3LpnfFGEzR9RtnsvKyvVSadMXuFy8cLPLYiy4S2boiJ0S-YhQdODqFY7_MbeiJB

And here is the underlying API (mine) that the CDN points to:
I get the full video if I hit that. It is 295,437 KB.

http://holojem-prod-cdn-api.azurewebsites.net/artifacts/11/283/332/0008%20Watch%20This%20Video.mp4?DYiNiOt7Q_9xGaZhscklXmcn0tlpDU649hQUD2n7WzgxfirhVQyzwch2-szLjDmUjAshEfe2ZsQ6ejEDR46QvHVKf5WneWFAz1vOQppOPfcBq3KCS11mZ3LpnfFGEzR9RtnsvKyvVSadMXuFy8cLPLYiy4S2boiJ0S-YhQdODqFY7_MbeiJB

Interestingly, the results are not consistent. When I hit the origin directly a second time from Postman, I got a file of 260,276 KB

When I downloaded from the origin in Chrome, I got 260,744 the first time and 262,144 KB the second time.

The origin is an ASPNET Core Web API

Comment: John can you share your CDN endpoint url?

Comment: Sure. Here is an example of requesting this file throught the CDN:
https://holojem-prod-files-cdn.azureedge.net/artifacts/11/283/332/0008%20Watch%20This%20Video.mp4?DYiNiOt7Q_9xGaZhscklXmcn0tlpDU649hQUD2n7WzgxfirhVQyzwch2-szLjDmUjAshEfe2ZsQ6ejEDR46QvHVKf5WneWFAz1vOQppOPfcBq3KCS11mZ3LpnfFGEzR9RtnsvKyvVSadMXuFy8cLPLYiy4S2boiJ0S-YhQdODqFY7_MbeiJB

Comment: @JohnWaters We are also facing a similar issue with azure cdn with standard akamai pricing tier. Have you found any workaround/solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to your CDN url, I found the CDN have compressed the file when I downloaded it.

You could run fiddler to catch the request as below:

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-troubleshoot-compression) : To check whether your files are being returned compressed, you need to use a tool like Fiddler or your browser's developer tools. Check the HTTP response headers returned with your cached CDN content. If there is a header named Content-Encoding with a value of gzip, bzip2, or deflate, your content is compressed.

So I suggest you could firstly check the compress setting in your azure portal.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-improve-performance#enabling-compression).

---

Update:

According to your two url, I have download both video. I found the website's size is a little more than the CDN's video.

The result is as below:

[image]

I have also compare the difference between these two file by using mediainfo --fullscan.

Just the Overall bit rate not the same.

One is 17.7 Mbps, another oen is 17.6 Mbps. There are both two minutes.

So I guess may be something wrong with your website to get the blob stream code.I suggest you could recheck it. If you still face the same issue, I suggest you could post some relevant code and the blob video url for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Interesting... BUT - compression is turned OFF on the CDN endpoint, AND mp4 is not in the default list of compressed MIME types. So in that case... could the compression be happening when I download from the Azure BLOB? Or my API? And.... smaller vidoes are not being clipped.

Comment: This is a link to a smaller file that comes down just fine. I dont see any compression headers on the download from Postman (I do not send accept-encoding: ....

Comment: https://holojem-prod-files-cdn.azureedge.net/artifacts/11/429/565/0008%20Watch%20Video%201.mp4?KYeLhGjjUkpiCdpFuGhSVUiGX9ozVU3S8dZI5QxZz1ffn0w5MtaNnUpaTyCBGeVWCr3GHnFj0b0IlYh8btl2wf9I2yU_NVpnqwydKn8m26YN_BDU8e9CseJ68V7Tw8MdccNKKbF9DqYgIMlKD3eVZ-rvFytugEB00MQFlZ68X-JltIEM